# How to close an open position on very next candlestick after it opens

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I want to create a strategy that opens a position when it my entry conditions are met and close it on the close of very next candlestick.

It opens a position but does not close it on next candlestick. How do I define the next upcoming candlestick?

```
'// Entry and exit logic
strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when=long_condition)
strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short, when=short_condition)
strategy.exit("Exit", from_entry="Buy", when=close)
strategy.exit("Exit", from_entry="Sell", when=close)`
```

I wrote this code and expected it to close on the next candlestick, but the buy position closes when the next sell position is opened and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

`strategy.exit()` is used when you want to close a position based on a price value.

You should use `strategy.close()` when you want to close your position conditionally.

Comment: By default, the script runs on each bar close. For me that means `right before close`. If I "close" a position, the triangle that represents the close will be drawn to the open of the next bar. If I turn on `process_orders_on_close` then the triangle will be drawn on the close of the bar. I have no idea why there is a difference as the script execution is advertised to be run on bar's close. (Further detail might reveal it is really `right before close` or `right after close`). Also, with a single trade open, there should be no difference between `.exit()` and `.close()`